# Process command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

When I used

```
ps -u root
```

command in Ubuntu it showed the following output?

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
  1 ?        00:00:02 init
  2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
  3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
  5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
  7 ?        00:00:02 rcu_sched
  8 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
  9 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
…
```

Where are the processes for vhand,bdflush,sched ? 
How do i know about these processes?

Comment: Try `ps auxw` to get all the processes

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you don't have only 9 processes.

You could use, eg:

```
pgrep sched
pgrep bdflush
```

or

```
ps -u root | grep sched
ps -u root | grep bdflush
```

If there is no output, than the processes are not running.

Comment: Did not work. It did not showed any process id and details